# Stop Windows 7 from creating .mdmp files in local folders

Tags: windows-7, freeze, windows-error-reporting, minidumps

I'm still using Windows 7 and about a month ago I made a reinstall. Since then, some programs (mainly games from Steam) start creating many .mdmp files in the folder where the executable resides. Notably, running the games through Steam (steam protocol, using the client) makes the games hang for 1-3 minutes or longer, and create a dozen or more of these minidumps. If I run the executable directly, maybe it creates a couple minidumps but loads fast/instantly for small ones. Yet they keep being created.

I've followed many guides about disabling error reporting and minidump creations, gone to advanced system config, regedit, services, disabled everything, rechecked, resetted and tried again... Example of places I've visited and read completely:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/disable-windows-error-reporting-werfault-exe-from-creating-crashdumps.3521038/
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings

One thing that I find really strange is that the minidumps are not created somewhere within Windows' folder, but in the same folder of the executable. And the freezing when launching stuff from Steam is horrible, and happens to several games, both new and old, some small games, others made in Unity or Unreal - but not all done in Unity or Unreal engines, just some. And, of course, none of this happened before the reinstall.

If these files would be created somewhere, I'd clean from time to time and done. If there was no freezing when launching from Steam, I'd not have even noticed. But it's driving me crazy. I've tried everything people have said about disabling errors, minidumps and such, to no avail. Maybe there's a magic reg key I've not found, maybe a service I've not disabled that's not really the same as what other people are talking about, maybe a Windows update that somehow went wrong and didn't install properly (had a bit of that due to the SHA thing).

I've ran out of ideas and it's driving me crazy. Please help me, suggest something. Except changing OS. I'm really desperate to solve this.

Comment: Get Blue Screen View from Nirsoft.net and determine the reasons for the crashes that generate the dumps. Better to solve the problem this way instead of letting it ferment.

Comment: Windows is not creating those dump files, the program is. They do that for debugging purposes. Find the real issue why Steam Games are doing this. Windows stores dump files in only 2 locations (root of C: and C:\Windows\System32\minidump, never program folders.

Comment: Thanks to a suggestion from a fellow member of a Steam group, I found the cause. Apparently before the reinstall I was running all programs as admin, but after the reinstall I didn't change the UAC settings nor anything about that yet. For some reason, that was causing Steam to behave like that. It doesn't explain why Steam does that anyway, but for me that is solved. Also thanks to Moab who confirmed my suspicions that this was actually related to Steam and wasn't a general system problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just running Steam as administrator. I added a comment with further details. Thanks everyone.